# Cannot render "KeyPropertyField" on existing object

Tags: python, wtforms

I'm new to Python. I'm developing an application on Google App Engine using webapp2, WTForms and Jinja2. My problem is that I cannot render fields of type `KeyPropertyField` on my templates, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Key' object has no attribute 'key'
```

The property in my model is defined as following:

```
pais = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Pais,required=True)
```

The field in the form is defined like this:

```
pais = KeyPropertyField('País',
                        reference_class=Pais,
                        get_label='nombre',
                        allow_blank=True,
                        validators=[validators.DataRequired()])
```

This is how I populate the form using the existing object:

```
form = DominiosForm(obj=dominio)
```

All data is correctly populated, when I hide my `KeyPropertyField` the form is correctly displayed with the data from the object.

I need help, this has me very frustrated.

Comment: Can we see more of the traceback?